# How to load parts of Ember.js on demand?

Tags: ember.js

I want to load parts of my Ember.js application on demand (app is structured with AMD but merged into a few big script files for production).

*An example:*

**Browse to '/'**

The user starts at `/`, the HTML loads the file `core.js` which contains Ember.js, the routings and the application controller + view.

**Browse to '/user/settings'**

So now the user browses to `/user/settings` for the first time. The views, controllers and templates for this are in `user.js` which is loaded via a script loader in the according route:

```
App.UserRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  enter: function(ctx) {
    this.ajaxLoadFiles("user.js", function() {
      // ???
    });
  }
});
```

**Problem**

Somehow Ember.js needs to *wait* for the script to load and then continue routing ... how do I do this?

Comment: For the templates part, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9469235/90741

Comment: Thanks :) -but I'm really looking for a "complete package" solution

Comment: NOTE: completely rewrote the question to make actual issue clearer

Answer (score 1):

I am using require.js, it is great for modularising your code!

You can clone the todoMVC AMD version to study here

https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/dependency-examples/emberjs_require

for further advice, see this post:

[Is there any way to split an Ember.js app across a few files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396677/is-there-any-way-to-split-an-ember-js-app-across-a-few-files)

Comment: I use require.js already :) The issue of the question is not how to just split the files - but how do LOAD them in the end.