# Ember.js Isn't Rendering?

Tags: ember.js, requirejs, amd

I'm using the newest version of Ember.js (currently pre-4.0) and I'm also using RequireJS. The problem comes when rendering all my templates. When all the templates are wrapped within script tags within the single html file, Ember will find and render all my templates. But when I separate them out using requirejs using the text plugin, it fails to render anything, or even show any errors.

**main.js**

```
(function(){

    window.App = Ember.Application.create({
        rootElement: '#wrapper',
        LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
    });

    requirejs.config({
        paths: {
            'jquery': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min',
        }, 

        // Use shim for plugins that does not support AMD
        shim: {

        },

    });

    window.compile = function(name, template) {
        return Ember.TEMPLATES[name] = Ember.Handlebars.compile(template);
    };

})();

define([
    'segmentation', 
    'text',

    // Controllers:
    'controllers/index',

    // Views:
    'views/index',

    // Routes:
    'routes/index',
    'router'
    ], function(Segmentation) {


    }
);
```

**router.js**

```
define([], function(){
    App.Router.map(function() {
        this.route("index", {
            path: "/"
        });
    });

    App.Router.reopen({
        location: 'history'
    });

});
```

**routes/index.js**

```
define([], function(){
    console.log(App);
    App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        setupController: function(controller) {
            console.log(1);
            // Set the IndexController's `title`
            controller.set('controller', this.container.lookup('controller:index'));
        },
        renderTemplate: function() {
            this.render('index');
        }
    });
});
```

and finally the template and view:

**application view**

```
define([
    'text!templates/application.html'
    ], function(template){

    App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile( template )
    });
});
```

**application template**

```
<center>
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
    <small>small</small>
</center>
<hr/>
<div id="content">{{outlet}}</div>
```

All this code dump probably wasn't needed, but just incase someone asks for it. When I wrap the templates within script tags and insert them into the html file, everything works like a charm.

**Any Solutions?**

Comment: There is a good repo linked in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776151/ember-js-and-requirejs?rq=1). It's hard to explain it better than he did.

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem.

Comment: found any way to solve this??...if templates are precompiled and give the name of template, its working..