# How do I include epf.js in a project using ember-tools?

Tags: optimization, requirejs, integration, epf, ember-tools

I'm integrating an ember project to use [ember-tools](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-tools) because I want nice build tools. My project also uses [epf](http://epf.io/), and I encountered a problem when I tried to include `epf.js` as a library. My instinct was just to lump `epf.js` into the `vendor/` folder that ember-tools had generated for me... but this doesn't work. When I run `ember build` it spits out the following:

```
Change detected: !config/app.js

   created: js/templates.js
   created: js/index.js
   created: js/application.js
build time: 493 ms
 Error: Cannot find module '/lib/version.js'
```

I think this is happening because `epf.js` uses [commonjs](http://www.commonjs.org/) syntax, as in

```
 require.define('/lib/index.js', function (module, exports, __dirname, __filename) {
        global.Ep = Ember.Namespace.create();
        require('/lib/version.js', module);
```

and ember-tools' build command thinks these require statements are declaring modules that it should build.

Is this a problem in general when using commonjs syntax? Is there some easy fix that will allow me to use ember-tools' build command to include `epf.js`, or should I keep a separate lib folder somewhere and just put a `<script>` tag in `index.html`?

**EDIT**

epf.js begins,

```
(function(global) {
```

and exports the `Ep` object as

```
global.Ep = Ember.Namespace.create();
```

This was causing problems, so I added `global = window;` and `var Ember = window.Em`. Later in the file there is a function called `require` which I renamed to `requireEPF`.

These terrible hacks have got me started, but I'd like to know if there is a better way.

Comment: A thought occurs to me: I suppose I could just rename the 'require' function in epf.js

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember.js and RequireJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776151/ember-js-and-requirejs)

Comment: Any update on this? I am currently stuck trying to use EPF 0.3.5 with ember-cli.